# Appium inspector does not split elements (React-Native app)

Tags: ios, react-native, appium, react-navigation-v5, automation-testing

React-Native app with + react-navigation-v5

After adding a screen into nested stack navigator can see picture like bellow on screenshots.

[[image] source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2Tsu.png)

[[image] appium inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqKfh.png)

Appium cannot split text elements inside view even with accessible={false}.

If I keep this screen out of nested stack on the level of root one - it works. Should I set some configs on navigation side or appium side?

Comment: Did you manage to get a solution for this?